# GPT OpenSource Project - Ingestion Issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, open-source

I am trying to get the following OpenSource project working:

`https://github.com/mayooear/gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain`

I am getting the following error when running the `npm run ingest` command:

```
error [Error: PineconeClient: Error calling upsert: Error: PineconeClient: Error calling upsertRaw: FetchError: The request failed and the interceptors did not return an alternative response]
c:\Users\Projects\chatpdf\gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain-main\gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain-main\scripts\ingest-data.ts:44
    throw new Error('Failed to ingest your data');
          ^


[Error: Failed to ingest your data]

Node.js v18.15.0
```

I have the following configured in my `.env` file:

```
OPENAI_API_KEY='sk-XXXXXXX'

# Update these with your Supabase details from your project settings > API and dashboard settings
PINECONE_API_KEY= '7XXXXXXXXX'
PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT= 'us-east1-gcp'
PINECONE_INDEX_NAME= 'default'
```

I have edited the `pinecone.ts` file and set my namespace to:

`const PINECONE_NAME_SPACE = 'pdfread'; //namespace is optional for your vectors`

Although not relevant at this stage I have edited the `makechain.ts` file to capture I am using GPT-3.5 as I am on the waitinglist for GPT-4:

`modelName: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',`

Finally, the pdf I am using ingesting is the `MorseVsFrederick` which came with the repo.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t change anything and it is now working. Maybe something to do with the pinecone infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was using the normal index name instead of the identifier kind of thing that comes below whatever index name you gave